# What is the shortcut to resize top/last 6 windows and display them all side by side?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts

I accidentally found this feature in Win 7. As it was accidental I'm not able to replicate or remember what excatly I did to achieve this.

What I did :

I wanted to maximize one browser window so took my mouse to the window and wanted to double clicked it, but did something else which **resized last six windows accessed including the browser windows and displayed them in sort of grid formation.**

```
|1|2|3|
|4|5|6|
```

[image: Magic of six windows]

I'm sure such feature exist

Edit: I might have involved both mouse & keyboard. It would be an interesting feature to unearth. Share pic after masking all vulnerable info and intentionally crippled it my shrinking too far ;) I don't want ppl to feel that I'm writing stories so share the picture

Comment: I know I'd get the obvious down rating ... becoz ppl have the general mentality to assume that *it does not exist when I don't know* was prepared mentaly

Comment: Right click the taskbar; _Show windows stacked_ or _Show windows side by side_?

Comment: Yes! yes thank you. Thanks a lot. thats cool to know @JosefZ request to share same answer section so this question can be close. Too bad I don't have any reputation to upvote the comment and I don't want to answer and then attribute it to you.

Comment: @JosefZ please post your comment as an answer, apparently that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To arrange your open windows, right-click an empty area of the taskbar, then click

- *Cascade windows*,
- *Show windows stacked*, or
- *Show windows side by side*.

**Resource**: [Manage multiple windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-multiple-windows#1TC=windows-7) Microsoft article.

> If you like to have a lot of programs open at once, it's a good idea
>   to understand how your program windows are organized on the taskbar
>   and how you can quickly sort through them. Learning to manage multiple
>   windows makes it easier to get to a window quickly and to arrange open
>   windows in a way that makes the most sense to you.